# How can I get the error line debugging Haxe for windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, haxe, haxeflixel, nme

I'm building a game using Haxe w/ HaxeFlixel in FlashDevelop, currently targeting windows platform.

While I get error messages in the console, I would like to know if I can get the error line too ( like flash does ).

I'm only getting something like this atm

> Error: Null Object Reference

I'm compiling with the NME command line `nme test windows -debug`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this issue on the [Haxe Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/haxelang/N_I8PJmDRNM) and here's "the official answer" from Hugh, the creator of hxcpp:

> Hi, There is a bug in the 3.0 HXCPP version that prevents the correct
>   stack dump in debug mode in this case. This is fixed in the SVN
>   version. You can also attach visual studio and put a function break
>   point in "hx::CriticalError" and examine the stack there.
>
> Hugh

The next version of hxcpp will have this issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add to the project file following lines?

```
<haxedef name="HXCPP_STACK_TRACE" />
<haxedef name="HXCPP_STACK_LINE" />
<haxedef name="HXCPP_DEBUG_LINK" />
```

I have same issue, but under linux - http://www.nme.io/community/forums/general-discussion/how-get-stack-trace-if-segmentation-fault-ocured-cpp-target/

Answer (score 0):

Try running from cmd. I'm sure, exception information wil be printed there. And don't forget to set '-debug' mode.